# How to handle a multivalue parameter in parametrised triggered Jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins, cron, continuous-integration, jenkins-pipeline

We have a Jenkins pipeline which has a parameter called PIPELINE_ACTIONS, set by two checkboxes. The two checkbox options are:

1. FlashFirmware
2. RunTests

So it can run with `PIPELINE_ACTIONS=FlashFirmware`, `PIPELINE_ACTIONS=RunTests` and `PIPELINE_ACTIONS=FlashFirmware,RunTests`.

We are now trying to use Build Triggers to trigger the pipeline with specific parameters (`Build periodically with parameters` option in Jenkins). We would like to run it with `PIPELINE_ACTIONS=FlashFirmware,RunTests` but for some reason it does not work. Sounds like a formatting issue and I can't find any documentation on how to pass more than one value to a parameter with a cron string.

The current cron string looks like this:

```
# Runs every 2 minutes
H/2 * * * * % FW_VERSION=4.0C3;PIPELINE_ACTIONS=FlashFirmware,RunTests;
```

When we print PIPELINE_ACTIONS, it is empty. We tried with brackes, whitespaces, etc. but no combination worked.

How can it be achieved?

EDIT
Here is how the PIPELINE_ACTIONS parameter is defined:
[image]

Comment: Can't you simply set the default value to be `FlashFirmware,RunTests` instead of specifying it in the cron string

Comment: Yes I could and that would work in this situation. But thinking more generally, there must be a way to give these parameters more than one value, right?

Answer (score 0):

For information, you can't use the default '`Build periodically`' option to schedule a Jenkins job with parameters. You need to install the [parameterized-scheduler plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/parameterized-scheduler/).

And With the [Active Choices plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/uno-choice/), you might want to configure your parameter as follows:

[image]

You can of course use the scripted or declarative style (if you're using `Jenkinsfile`) to define your Active Choice parameter.

Finally schedule your build like the following:

```
H/2 * * * * %PIPELINE_ACTIONS=FlashFirmware,RunTests;FW_VERSION=1.0.0
```

Comment: I'm using the "Build periodically with parameters" option. And I'm using a Jenkinsfile to define my parameters. The only doubt I have is how to pass more than one value to a single parameter. In your answer you have "PIPELINE_ACTIONS=FlashFirmware,RunTests;" but that doesn't work. It only works when I have one of the two. Any documentation on how to pass more than one value for multi-value fields like checkboxes?

Comment: As, I said, you need to use the parameterized-scheduler or it won't work. There is an example showing how to trigger build using Jenkinsfile: https://plugins.jenkins.io/parameterized-scheduler/

Comment: But I'm already using it. I told you I'm using "Build periodically with parameters", which is exactly what the Parameterized Scheduler tells you on that page. And in the examples, there is no field which more than one value.

Comment: I have tested what I proposed as solution and it works for me.
Are you using the Active choices plugin also ?

Comment: No, the parameter is an "Extendend Choice Parameter", parameter type "Check Boxes" with a comma as delimeter. I'll edit the question to add a screenshot. And we don't have the Active Choice plugin so we're trying to make it work without it.

Comment: Ok, indeed, my solution works with Active choices plugin. I'll try to test the Extended Choice Parameter plugin and tell you if I have something working